# Mysql RDS Authentication security

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

In my company we login into MySQL database using a ssh tunnel.

The problem is that we need to create credential login for each customer and programmer .

Whatis the best way to manage this credentials?
For now,  there is only one user and password for each customer. So we use the same  credential for one customer.

PD: We are using RDS, so maybe some tool of Amazon could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways:

1. Using CREATE USER, GRANT PRIVILEGES per user using MySQL prompt once logged in using master account
2. Using AWSAuthenticationPlugin .. It allows you to link your MySQL user directly with IAM user.

Refer [Creating a Database Account - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.DBAccounts.html)